# Calculate selection as percentage of total

Tags: spotfire

I need to let users select some (1+) categories and then calculate % of values in that category compared to all values in current filtering.

I could achieve to show marked vs total using subsets, however I can't write an expression across subsets.

e.g. in first column I would need to get result 6 / 20 = 0.3

Notes

- I need a generic solution, not one based on structure of my sample dataset
- Total should be total of current filtering, not total of all data

[image]

Sample data:

| country | year | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FR | 2001 | 4 |
| FR | 2002 | 3 |
| FR | 2003 | 5 |
| FR | 2004 | 1 |
| FR | 2005 | 3 |
| FR | 2006 | 2 |
| FR | 2007 | 3 |
| FR | 2008 | 3 |
| FR | 2009 | 2 |
| FR | 2010 | 1 |
| FR | 2011 | 2 |
| FR | 2012 | 3 |
| FR | 2013 | 5 |
| FR | 2014 | 3 |
| FR | 2015 | 3 |
| FR | 2016 | 2 |
| FR | 2017 | 5 |
| FR | 2018 | 2 |
| FR | 2019 | 4 |
| FR | 2020 | 5 |
| DE | 2001 | 4 |
| DE | 2002 | 2 |
| DE | 2003 | 2 |
| DE | 2004 | 2 |
| DE | 2005 | 3 |
| DE | 2006 | 5 |
| DE | 2007 | 3 |
| DE | 2008 | 4 |
| DE | 2009 | 3 |
| DE | 2010 | 4 |
| DE | 2011 | 4 |
| DE | 2012 | 2 |
| DE | 2013 | 4 |
| DE | 2014 | 4 |
| DE | 2015 | 4 |
| DE | 2016 | 2 |
| DE | 2017 | 4 |
| DE | 2018 | 4 |
| DE | 2019 | 3 |
| DE | 2020 | 3 |
| CH | 2001 | 2 |
| CH | 2002 | 1 |
| CH | 2003 | 1 |
| CH | 2004 | 2 |
| CH | 2005 | 5 |
| CH | 2006 | 4 |
| CH | 2007 | 1 |
| CH | 2008 | 4 |
| CH | 2009 | 2 |
| CH | 2010 | 3 |
| CH | 2011 | 2 |
| CH | 2012 | 2 |
| CH | 2013 | 1 |
| CH | 2014 | 1 |
| CH | 2015 | 3 |
| CH | 2016 | 1 |
| CH | 2017 | 4 |
| CH | 2018 | 3 |
| CH | 2019 | 4 |
| CH | 2020 | 3 |
| IT | 2001 | 3 |
| IT | 2002 | 5 |
| IT | 2003 | 1 |
| IT | 2004 | 5 |
| IT | 2005 | 4 |
| IT | 2006 | 5 |
| IT | 2007 | 5 |
| IT | 2008 | 1 |
| IT | 2009 | 1 |
| IT | 2010 | 4 |
| IT | 2011 | 2 |
| IT | 2012 | 4 |
| IT | 2013 | 3 |
| IT | 2014 | 5 |
| IT | 2015 | 4 |
| IT | 2016 | 2 |
| IT | 2017 | 3 |
| IT | 2018 | 3 |
| IT | 2019 | 3 |
| IT | 2020 | 2 |
| ES | 2001 | 2 |
| ES | 2002 | 1 |
| ES | 2003 | 2 |
| ES | 2004 | 4 |
| ES | 2005 | 1 |
| ES | 2006 | 1 |
| ES | 2007 | 4 |
| ES | 2008 | 1 |
| ES | 2009 | 1 |
| ES | 2010 | 2 |
| ES | 2011 | 2 |
| ES | 2012 | 1 |
| ES | 2013 | 2 |
| ES | 2014 | 1 |
| ES | 2015 | 5 |
| ES | 2016 | 4 |
| ES | 2017 | 5 |
| ES | 2018 | 4 |
| ES | 2019 | 1 |
| ES | 2020 | 2 |